# MaskInput number format show dash (-) instead of zero

Tags: c#

Want to format my number value if number is zero then should show dash ('-') sign instead of zero. what would be the format or MaskInput?

e.g.:

```
========================================
MyNumberFormatted      MyNumberNoFormat
========================================
       -                     0
       5                     5
       -                     0
       1                     1
========================================
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SectionSeparator)

```
string conditionalFormat = "{0:##;-##;-}"; // {0:positive;negative;zero}
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(conditionalFormat, 1));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(conditionalFormat, -1));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(conditionalFormat, 0));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/BgFc8j

Comment: 1+ thx,   can you suggest what would be maskinput format? like grid.columns[0].MaskInput = xxxxxxxx

Comment: it would be `##;-##;-`

Comment: using ultragrid control winforms and this is what am doing.      grdResult.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].MaskInput = @"##;-##;-";

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this framework so I can't try this. Isn't there a format property? `grdResult.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Format = "##;-##;-";`

Comment: its works I never notice format property and works with "##;-##;-" many thanks to you.